# Google Map based on ASP.NET/SQL database field "Google Map Link"

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008, google-maps

I have a field in sql server 2008 named "Google Maps URL" in which I am storing Google map URL. Now I want to display Google map based on that field custom map URL value. How can I achieve it?

Comment: Is a custom map url or is the googe.maps.api url like this: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false

Comment: Can you give an example of such url? where do yo want to display the map image? can't you open a new browser window or IFrame?

Comment: Example: https://maps.google.nl/maps?q=florijn+34+dronten&hnear=Florijn+34,+8253+DM+Dronten,+Flevoland&t=h&z=16 @saeedserpooshan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To show google maps, you have several options:

- [Google Maps JavaScript API (v3)](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial)

  It use javascript api to load and show maps based on given parameters and options. (see documentation in specified link)
- Google Maps Image APIs: [Static Maps API (V2)](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/staticmaps/index) and [Street-View Image API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/streetview/index)

  The **Google Static Maps API** lets you embed a Google Maps image on your web page without requiring JavaScript or any dynamic page loading. The Google Static Map service creates your map based on URL parameters sent through a standard HTTP request and returns the map as an image (**< img >** element) you can display on your web page.
  The sample url will be: http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=New+York,NY&zoom=13&size=600x300&key={API_KEY} , where {API_KEY} is a key you get free from google (see documentation)
- Using simple map urls retrieved from http://maps.google.com by clicking the 'Link' button on top-left side of the map you see at the time. for example add this **iframe** to your web page to view the map:

  `<iframe width="425" height="350" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="https://maps.google.com/?ie=UTF8&amp;ll=37.055177,-95.668945&amp;spn=21.547507,28.256836&amp;t=m&amp;z=5&amp;output=embed"></iframe>`